# Include file during SQL table creation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, include

I have two files: Table creation and Table insert

One creates a table with rows, and the other inserts data into those rows

Rather than editing the rows name/type in each file, I tried including rows.php but I get an error

**rows.php looks like this:**

```
Row1 CHAR(15),
Row2 CHAR(15),
Row3 CHAR(15),

**tablecreation.php looks like this:**
$sql = "CREATE TABLE TableTest 
(
<?php include 'rows.php'; ?>
)";

**tableinsert.php looks lkike this:**
$sql = "INSERT INTO TableTest 
(
<?php include 'rows.php'; ?>
)";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Echo $sql see the result

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `create table` and for `insert` with a column list are different.

The `create table` statement has data types.  The `insert` statement does not.

So, the following generates an error:

```
insert into TableTest(Row1 char(15), . . .)
```

Because the data type is not allowed in that context.